# Telegram parser on python/telethon does not work properly

Tags: python, parsing, telegram, telethon

I've wrote a telegram API parser which resends messages from one group to another but it works only for 5-10 seconds while I'm logged in Telegram. After this few seconds are over telegram throws me out of my account on all devices and my code stops working. How can I fix and make it work properly? Help me please!

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, events

api_id = '*******'
api_hash = '*************************'
#phone = '*********'

DESTINATION_GROUP_ID = -1001964185842 #our channel for recieving messages
SOURCE_GROUP_ID = -1001923879320 #information source channels

with TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash) as client:
    #for message in client.iter_messages(chat):
        #print(message.sender_id, ':', message.text)

    async def forward_message_to_destination(message):
        await client.send_message(DESTINATION_GROUP_ID, message)
        print(f"Message forwarded: {message.text}")

    @client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=SOURCE_GROUP_ID))
    async def forward_messages(event):
        message = event.message
        await forward_message_to_destination(message)

    with client:
        client.run_until_disconnected()
```

The code should resend anything from SOURCE_GROUP_ID to DESTINATION_GROUP_ID and it does but only while you are logged in telegram app (on your phone or PC) BUT when you log in using this code (in my case in pycharm) you get thrown out in about 5-10 seconds.

Comment: Telegram kicking you out might be a signal that Telegram doesn't like what you're doing. Remember to abide by Telegram's ToS. Copying content between channels is probably not intended.

Comment: How can I know that for sure? I know that when you create a group you can choose whether to let people copy your content or not. This code "works" only for groups where copying is allowed so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: You can't know that for sure because Telegram gets to decide the rules and can change them at any time. Telethon only does what you tell it to do, except for keep-alive pings and fetching updates if gaps are detected which should not be a problem. If Telegram kicks you out, there's unfortunately not much you can do.